# ¿Cómo puedo pasar los datos de un dataframe a dos arreglos?

Tags: python, pandas

Verán, tengo un archivo que leo y paso a un dataframe. Luego lo convierto a números binarios, lo que quiero hacer es pasar esos datos binarios, pero no sé cómo, este es el primer código que probé:

```
from __future__ import print_function 
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize  
import numpy as np

#--------Preproceso de datos---------------

   #--------------Lectura del archivo------------
with open('cambios.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)  

   #-----Extrayendo los datos en una tabla y creando el dataframe-------
tabla = json_normalize(data["MisCanciones"])
partitura = pd.DataFrame(tabla,columns=["genero", "instrumento","valorcompas","metronomo", "duracioncancion","numerocancion","nota","escala","alteracion","posicion","figura","numerocompas","efecto","clave"] )


   #-----Pasando datos categóricos a númericos (Binario)
df_nota =pd.get_dummies(partitura, columns=["genero", "instrumento","valorcompas","metronomo", "duracioncancion","numerocancion","nota","escala","alteracion","posicion","figura","numerocompas","efecto","clave"])

x = df_nota[:,0:5]
y = df_nota[:,6:77]
```

Pero eso me da error. Luego probe pasarlo a un arreglo y de ahí convertirlo:

```
from __future__ import print_function 
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize  
import numpy as np

#--------Preproceso de datos---------------

   #--------------Lectura del archivo------------
with open('cambios.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)  

   #-----Extrayendo los datos en una tabla y creando el dataframe-------
tabla = json_normalize(data["MisCanciones"])
partitura = pd.DataFrame(tabla,columns=["genero", "instrumento","valorcompas","metronomo", "duracioncancion","numerocancion","nota","escala","alteracion","posicion","figura","numerocompas","efecto","clave"] )
for n in partitura:
    x = partitura[0,1,2,3,4,5]
    y = partitura[6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]

entrada = pd.get_dummies(x)
salida = pd.get_dummies(y)
```

Pero me tira el siguiente error: KeyError: (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
¿Cómo puedo arreglarlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error se debe a que intentas acceder a las columnas de un `pd.DataFrame` como si fuera un `np.array`, y estos a diferencia de los array numpy se acceden mediante el nombre del indice y no del indice como tal, una manera en la que puedes hacer lo que intentas es usando `pd.DataFrame.columns`, que retorna un `pd.core.indexes` con el nombre de las columnas, y el cual si es posible iterar:

```
# Primero Generamos el nombre de las columnas y filtramos segun sean para x o y
nombres_columnas = df_nota.columns
columnas_x = nombres_columnas[:5]
columnas_y = nombres_columnas[5:77]

# Y una vez obtenidas se filtra el df dependiendo del nombre de las columnas
x = df_notas[columnas_x]
y = df_notas[columnas_y]
```

Eso deberia solucionar el problema, y solo como dato, en el segundo caso ocurre algo parecido, cuando iteras un `pd.DataFrame` lo que obtienes es el nombre de la columna, y no los valores de las mismas.

No tengo manera de replicar y ver si funciona, en caso de que no te funcione o no sea lo que ocupes hazmelo saber, saludos

Comment: Gracias! me sirvió bastante